# Can an abbreviation of a verb be classified as a nominalisation?

Tags: abbreviations, parts-of-speech, acronyms, initialisms, nominalizations

For example, in the abbreviation for the fictional organisation "SCP Foundation", "SCP" is short for "Secure, Contain, Protect."

Would this classify the term "SCP" as a nominalisation, since it is a conversion of word class from verb to noun? This seems to make sense, but I have not been able to find any supporting evidence specific to this case online.

This also seems like a special case, since not a single word can be a noun for the entire abbreviation to count as a nominalisation. In regards to that, though, can you classify individual letters of an abbreviation as nominalisations, such as the letter "C" in "CIA (Central Intelligence Agency)"?

Comment: No, it's just an abbreviation or initialism, like GOP or UN. What the words used to be before they became just letters is rarely recalled, and certainly not their part of speech.

Comment: I'd agree. Conversions result in words in the lexis rather than names in catalogues.

Comment: I think I've come to a better understanding on what conversion of word class is; since an abbreviation changes the form of the lexis therein through contraction, conversion of word class is not possible since form is not retained. Would this be correct?